# python pandas, подскажите как при выгрузке сделать так чтобы не перезаписывался файл, а создавался новый

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['items'])
df.to_csv(r'out.csv', index=False)
```

всё это находится в цикле while, поэтому при каждой итерации файл перезаписывается , как сделать так , чтобы файл out.csv не перезаписывался , а создавался новый с дефолтным именем ? В документации pandas не нашел ничего по этому поводу.

И подскажите как другим способом решить эту проблему и где хранить промежуточные результаты цикла ? В переменной вне цикла не получится я так понимаю ? Если хранить в массиве, то как это сделать правильно ? на вход я получаю json как не нарушить его структуру ? 
Вот скрипт :

```
import vk_api
import json
import pandas as pd
import time


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('your_login', 'your_password')  # логин и пароль
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()





def main():


    count_in = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public')
    count = count_in['count']
    print(count)
    offset = 0
    a = []
    while count > 0:

        y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=offset,
                                 fields='contacts')

        count = count - 1000
        offset = offset+1000
        time.sleep(3)

        data = y
        df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['items'])
        df.to_csv(r'.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: можете пояснить как вы понимаете: `"создавался новый с дефолтным именем ?"` ? Лично я понимаю слово "дефолтный" как константу... Можете также пояснить что вы хотите получить в результате работы цикла? Т.е. описать задачу шире...

Comment: я хочу чтобы при каждой итерации цикла создавался файл условно "новый файл.csv" на следующей итерации "новый файл2.csv", на следующей "новый файл3.csv". Это грубо говоря. В идеале конечно весь результат в итоге выгрузить в один csv файл, но я своим умом до этого пока не могу дойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы писать результат в разные (пронумерованные) CSV файлы:

```
i = 1

while count > 0:

    ...
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['items'])
    df.to_csv(r'/path/to/out_{:03}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
    i += 1
```

---

но лучше собрать все данные в один список и преобразовать его в единственный DataFrame и сохранить его как CSV (который будет содержать все данные):

```
data = []
while count > 0:
    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=offset,
                             fields='contacts')
    data.append(y['items'])
    count = count - 1000
    offset = offset+1000
    time.sleep(3)

# we do it _outside_ of the loop!
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
df.to_csv(r'big_fat_resulting_file.csv', index=False)
```

---

или еще проще - можно дописывать (добавлять) новые данные в CSV файл:

```
i = 0
step = 1000

for count in range(count_in['count'], 0, -step):
    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=i*step,
                             fields='contacts')
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(y['items'])
    df.to_csv(r'result.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=(i==0))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: почему бы `for count in range(count_in['count'], 0, -1000)` вместо while цикла не использовать?

Comment: @jfs, можно и так. Я отвечал на главный вопрос ...

Comment: конечно, но если это не мешает пониманию, то следует лучших практик придерживаться (fortran можно на любом языке писать :). Это и автору и другим читателям полезно будет.

Comment: когда использую: write_header = True
while count > 0:
    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_public', offset=offset,
                             fields='contacts')
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(y['items'])
    df.to_csv(r'result.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=write_header)
    write_header = False   парсит почему-то 3 человека и просто заполняет csv файл этими 3 людьми , запросов не 1000 а всего 3